# FetchedResultsController - Contain 2 search results - Core Data iOS

Tags: uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Can I perform a fetch on 2 objects - and place in one tableview.

For example, having a PERSON obj that has 2, one to many relationships with an obj called SPORTS and another called CARS.

Can the fetched results controller contain the results of the the persons, sports and cars, then are placed in a single TV in sections of sports and cars?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Decided to fetch just the Person Entity (Person.hasCars, Person.hasSports), and the use the NSSET of each cars and sports and solved my issues.